# How to turn Docker support on/off for .NET Core applications?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web App, and added Docker Support for testing purposes. But I also want to build this app targeting my local machine.

I cannot find a way to turn docker support on/off in VS 2017.

I tried to remove  `<DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>` section but no luck.

Is there any easy way to change target?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just right click on the web application, and select `Set as StartUp Project`.

If you want to debug/run with Docker container, you select Docker project and do the same.

[image]

Comment: ahhhh I did not realized it was (docker) coming as a project type. Thanks for the hint.